# Drupal 7 - Trying to get term reference node, from html.tpl

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to access the value of a term reference (field_test), from a node, in html.tpl.

First I need to load a specific node, check if the term reference of this node is the same as another value that i have already in the page.

Is someone knows how to access that term reference, with ne $node object?

I have get already the $node, but i cannot access the "field_test" which is inside the $node.

Thanks

emb

Comment: you're better off trying this in node.tpl.php. Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: @ScottJoudry is right - doing so at html.tpl.php, where you don't even know if you are displaying node at all, does not sound as the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you'll want to test for a node, then check for the field and then print it to your template. This should work for you:

```
<?php

if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
        if(isset($node->field_test['und'][0]['value'])) {
            print $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
        }       
}
```

?>

That's code for Drupal 7